# Disable code analysis for current file in ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

In ReSharper 4.x there was a shortcut (Ctrl+8) for turning off the code analysis for the current file, but I cannot find the equivalent in ReSharper 5.0. Anyone knows where to find it?

The reason I want this is because I want to disable ReSharper when editing XAML-files (because it's just incredibly slow...), and I don't want to go through the dialog under "Options > Code Inspection > Settings > Edit items to skip" for each and every xaml-file. And I want to turn it back on temporarily when I need the code inspection.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>?

This shortcut is bound to the `ReSharper_EnableDaemon`-command, so you are free to change it to whatever you want.

Comment: sigh...you do wonder at times how it is possible to hit this key combination _at random_

Comment: This also holds for ReSharper 6.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in VS2013/ReSharper 8.1. When I press the keystroke I see a prompt that tells me to use my arrow keys to move code. I've verified the command in the Keyboard options. Am I missing something?

Comment: This disables it just for that file. I want to turn "code analysis" on/off globally. Couldn't find a command for that.