# Resharper renaming file active code analysis

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have a problem with ReSharper, it is not working with some files. I have tried all possibilities (suspend ReSharper and activate it again), clean the cache, etc.)

I will explain my problem in more detail. I have my "HomeController.cs", and it has the HomeController Class. I don't know why, the Resharper code analysis is not working with this file. My trick to solve provisionally my problem: If I change the name of the file (not the class), the Resharper code analysis works fine.

If I create a new controller, Resharper code analysis works fine with this class and file  too.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147445/disable-code-analysis-for-current-file-in-resharper) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725692/is-there-a-way-to-disable-resharper-for-a-specific-file), but it does not work for me.

All my problems begin when I changed the namespace of some files/class.

IDE: Visual Studio 2013 Update 1, Resharper Version 8.2.1 Full Edition

Can somebody explain to me where I can configure Resharper or any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: The problem happens with Razor Views too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples" nuget package installed to your solution? If yes, you do, it is the reason why there is no R# in files which come with such package. ReSharper considers all files from nuget packages as NonUserCode. Some more information you may find [here](http://blog.beabigrockstar.com/cleanup-code-resharper-available/).

To remove "non-user code" restriction for the solution files from Nuget samples package, please open "packages.config" file and remove the following string:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples" version="{Version}" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Then save the file and reopen the solution.